# Событие Click для навигационного меню

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня! Перерыл кучу сайтов, но так и не нашел нужного ответа. Ситуация такова: Есть навигационное меню

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">Выпадающее_меню_1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_1</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_3</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </li>
    <li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">Выпадающее_меню_2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_1</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_3</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Замысел таков, чтоб при клике по "Выпадающее_меню_1" к нему добавлялся класс "active", при повторном клике он убирался. В стилях CSS я прописал правило, что  при этих действиях "dropdown" соответственно проявляется или скрывается.
Но тут появилась ситуация, когда пользователь при открытом меню "Выпадающее_меню_1" нажимает "Выпадающее_меню_2" (должно закрыться первое меню и открыться второе). Смог добиться только того, чтоб при клике с первого открытого меню по второму скрывались оба выпадающих меню, но второе никак не хочет открываться...

**JS**

```
    $('.menu-dropdown').click(function (e) {
        var activeLink  =   $('.menu-dropdown');
        if (activeLink.hasClass('active')) {
            $('.menu-dropdown').removeClass("active");
            e.stopPropagation();
        } 
        else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })

    $('body').click(function () {
        var link = $('.menu-dropdown');
        if (link.hasClass('active')) {
            $(".menu-dropdown").removeClass("active");
        }
    })
```

Да, еще дописал функцию, чтоб при любом нажатии в другой области снимался класс "active".

Прошу помочь, с данной ситуацией, так как уже два дня сижу, и ни на шаг не продвинулся...

Comment: Мой ответ вам помог?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var $li = $(".menu-dropdown");
    $li.each(function(indx, li) {
      li = $(li);
      li.on({
        "click": function(event) {
          !$(event.target).closest(".dropdown").length && $li.not(li.toggleClass("active")).removeClass("active") && event.preventDefault()
        }
      })
    });
    $(document).click(function(event) {
      if (!$(event.target).closest(".navbar-nav").length) $li.removeClass("active")
    })
```

```css
.menu-dropdown ul {
  display: none;
}
.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">Выпадающее_меню_1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-dropdown"><a href="#">Выпадающее_меню_2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Текст_3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто при клике на каждый пункт меню поставь метод hide() на все другие пункты и снятие класса active

И вместо условий на проверку состояния можно просто добавить .toogleClass('active'), будет сниматься класс если он есть и добавляться если его нет

```
$('.menu-dropdown').click(function (e) {
        $('.menu-dropdown').toggleClass("active");
    })
```

Comment: Думаю это не совсем грамотно но всё же

Comment: В том то и дело, что я и с "toggleClass" пробовал, в простой конструкции, но такое впечатление, что без конструкции if else не получится...

Comment: @hochru Пишите так и добавьте методы закрытия других пунктов при клике на один

Comment: В том то и дело, что не знаю как добавить методы закрытия. Знаний еще не хватает((

Comment: @hochru Да в событие click на каждый элмент добавьте:
 $("Элемент1").hide();$("Элемент2").hide(); кроме элемента на который кликнули естественно, то есть будут при клике на элемент закрываться все элементы которые вы прописали

Comment: Через "removeClass" пробовал, а "hide" не подходит так как display:block срабатывает и анимация CSS пропадает

Comment: @hochru А ну так тогда удаляйте классы у всех других, схема же от этого не меняется, а что за анимация? Есть же еще fadeout и clideup

Comment: .navbar-nav > .menu-dropdown .dropdown
 opacity: 0
 visibility: hidden
 transform: translateY(30px)

Comment: .navbar-nav > .menu-dropdown.active .navbar-dropdown
 opacity: 1
 visibility: visible
 transform: translateY(0)
 display: block

Comment: @hochru А при удалении класса анимация пропадает?

Comment: Угу, блок сдвигается на 30px вниз при этом растворяется